# If $z_1,z_2,z_3 \in \Bbb C$ such that $|z_1|=|z_2|= |z_3|=\left|\dfrac{1}{z_1}+\dfrac{1}{z_2}+\dfrac{1}{z_3}\right|=1$, then$|z_1+z_2+z_3|$ is?

Tags: complex-numbers

If  $z_1, z_2, z_3$  are complex numbers such that  $|z_1|=|z_2|= |z_3| $=  $\left|\dfrac{1}{z_1}+\dfrac{1}{z_2}+\dfrac{1}{z_3}\right| = 1$, then$|z_1 + z_2 + z_3|$ is :

(A)  equal to 1(B)  less than 1   (C)  greater than 3          (D)  equal to 3

I am not able to proceed because everything = 1 including the answer which is equal to 1

Comment: The whole sum of reciprocal is also in modulas

Comment: Done the modification

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}1&=&\left|\dfrac{1}{z_1}+\dfrac{1}{z_2}+\dfrac{1}{z_3}\right|\\ &=&\left|\dfrac{1}{z_1}\cdot\frac{\bar z_1}{\bar z_1}+\dfrac{1}{z_2}\cdot\frac{\bar z_2}{\bar z_2}+\dfrac{1}{z_3}\cdot\frac{\bar z_3}{\bar z_3}\right|\\
&=&\left|\dfrac{\bar z_1}{|z_1|^2}+\dfrac{\bar z_2}{|z_2|^2}+\dfrac{\bar z_3}{|\bar z_3|^2}\right|\\
&=&\left|\bar z_1+\bar z_2+\bar z_3\right|\\
&=&\left|\overline{z_1+z_2+z_3}\right|\\
&=&\left|z_1+z_2+z_3\right|
\end{eqnarray}